# SSIS to create flat files from data in two tables

Tags: ssis

i need to create a flat file from data in 2 separate tables which looks like below

table 1:-

```
MessageID|StoreID
  1        1234
  2        5678
```

table 2:-

```
MessageID|ProductID|Quantity|PickMethod
  1        1111       3         Z
  1        0923       5         G
  1        4323       1         Z
  2        9343       2         G
  2        2334       6         Z
  2        2331       7         Z
```

in the above 2 tables MessageID is foreignKey b/w 1 and table 2

i need to create a flat file which looks  below

```
0,xyz,20130303
1,1234
2,1111,3,Z
2,0923,5,G
2,4323,1,z
1,5678
2,9343,2,G
2,2334,6,Z
2,2331,7,Z
9,10
```

in the above file row starting with 0 is header and then row starting with 1 is for a storeID and rows starting with 2 is details for a particular store(productid,quantity ...)

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but I think you'll need to create a custom script.

Comment: Also, I think you should revise your output example. First column may mismatch...

Comment: Since different rows have a different number of columns, you can't do this directly with a regular result set (because every row in a result set has the same number of columns). So you'll need to write some custom script code to do this, or perhaps a [custom data flow component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136078.aspx) if it would work better for you.